# Strategy for subsequences/slices of given sequence (sub-lists/sub-tuples/sub-strings/etc.)

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

How can I write a strategy for subsequences of given sequence?

For example given a `list`

```py
elements = list(range(5))
```

I want a strategy

```py
sub_elements = *strategy*(elements)
```

which generates

```
[]
[0]
[0, 2]
[1, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

simple approach with combination of [`strategies.lists`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#hypothesis.strategies.lists) & [`strategies.sampled_from`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#hypothesis.strategies.sampled_from) like

```py
>>> from hypothesis import strategies
>>> strategies.lists(strategies.sampled_from(elements))
```

won't work because it doesn't take into account original elements count.

Answer (score 1):

The main idea is to use [`strategies.slices`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#hypothesis.strategies.slices) and then select items based on them

```py
from collections import abc
from typing import TypeVar

from hypothesis import strategies
from hypothesis.strategies import SearchStrategy

Sequence = TypeVar('Sequence', bound=abc.Sequence)


def subsequences(sequence: Sequence) -> SearchStrategy[Sequence]:
    return strategies.builds(sequence.__getitem__,
                             strategies.slices(max(len(sequence), 1)))
```

it's pretty short, straightforward and should work for any sequences that support slicing like `list`s, `tuple`s and `str`ings (even for `range`s, which is great IMO).

Example:

```py
>>> elements = list(range(5))
>>> sub_elements = subsequences(elements)
[1, 3]
>>> sub_elements.example()
[4]
>>> sub_elements.example()
[0, 2, 4]
```

The only problem with that approach that we can't create all possible subsequences (like `[0, 1, 4]` for `elements` from OP).

It can be solved with [`strategies.permutations`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#hypothesis.strategies.permutations) like

```py
from operator import getitem
from typing import (List,
                    Sequence,
                    TypeVar)

from hypothesis import strategies
from hypothesis.strategies import SearchStrategy

Element = TypeVar('Element')


def sub_lists(sequence: Sequence[Element]) -> SearchStrategy[List[Element]]:
    return strategies.builds(getitem,
                             strategies.permutations(sequence),
                             strategies.slices(max(len(sequence), 1)))
```

but we lose original sequence type.